# Lazy loading issues with IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using Asp.NET Identity. I created an IdentityDbContext with a number of entities (*linear relationship: user→account→statement*).

The Account.Statements navigational property is null event when instanced by the context:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var account = ctx.Account.Create();
    Debug.Assert(account != null); // fails.
}
```

All navigational properties where correctly assigned to a lazy loading collection when `MyContext` derived from `DbContext`.

Is this a issue of Asp.Net Identity? Is there some way to get this right?

Comment: You are asserting `account != null`, did you mean `account.Statements != null`? Anyway check that the Statements property is declared as virtual and initialize it inside your constructor:

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx), DbSet's `Create` method ***does not*** attach the object to the context. I found out that, if I attach the object, the properties are properly assigned proxy collections.

Also, this is not a real problem: I simply could create an instance of a collection myself and afterwards add the object to the collection, Entity Framework would correcly submit related items.